# Do I have to mod my xbox 360 console to play region free games?

Tags: xbox-360, region-lock

Do I have to mod my xbox 360 console to play region free games?
I bought my Xbox 360 in Japan so I would like to know if i have to mod my console to play region free games as I live in south africa...

Answer (score 3):

By definition, a region-free game will play on any console regardless of its region. Modding your console is only useful to play region-locked games on a console not from the correct region.

Answer (score 1):

Region-free by definition means that the game is not locked to a certain country or region, see what I did there?

Example. Say I make a game and I develop it in Japan. I want it only to be sold and played in Japan. I would "region-lock" it. So if someone decided to order my game in America. It couldn't be played. IF

I think you're asking if you need to mod your console to play region-locked consoles and that answer is technically yes.